# Monitor not turning off in 14.04

Tags: ati, suspend, brightness, monitor

I have a freshly installed ubuntu 14.04.

In settings "Brightness and locking" I had the following Settings:

> Turn monitor off after "10 Minutes"
>
> Locking: On
>
> Monitor locking after "5 Minutes" and "Ticked" Ask for password ...

(Sorry my System is in German, hopefully I have the right translation).

What happens:

System gets locked after 5 Minutes but never turns off.
I always see the login Screen.

I tried to switch the times (First turn off, then login etc...) but always the same result.
I can, however manually select standby. Then the monitor switches off. But then i can't wake up the system anymore. No Mouse or Keyboard reaction...

I have the standard Ubuntu graphics driver installed. No extra atm (fglrx) etc.

Here is a example screenshot of my settings. Monitor does not turn off after 10 Minutes.
I also tried "Monitor off after 5 Minutes and Screenlock after 10 Minutes". Monitor does not turn off.

[image: Screenshot settings]

Because of 2 comments telling me "It turns off AFTER 10 Minutes". Well I know it's not meant to turn off immediately. But it is not turning off after 10 minutes and not after 30 minutes and not tomorrow ;)

Comment: It turns off when **Inactive for "10 Minutes"**

Comment: No. It doesn't.

Comment: you have asked to lock after 5 mins, and display turn off after 10 mins... after 10 mins it will off... if not please update screenshot for your settings...

Comment: It does NOT turn off! No matter what times I set.

Comment: try lock->on, and select "Lock screen after : Screen turns off"

Comment: Well. Please again read the question. As i write: No matter what settings, it does not turn off.

Comment: wait let me check with my system and I will reply to you...

Comment: Now I understand your problem, unfortunately I didn't have a solution still now, Can you update screen-shot for All settings ->  Displays; and tell me please weather you using laptop or desktop system?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your effort. I'm using a desktop system with triple monitor setup. What do you need to know from display settings?

Comment: Another possibility is external vibration. A sensitive optical mouse can keep a system running (due to loud music or other vibration) virtually indefinitely.

Comment: @rechengehirn, try with `xset -s on ; xset +dpms` also open a terminal and watch for X idle if does reset may hardware sensibility `watch -n1 xprintidle` (should install xprintidle 1st)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like its a bug.  See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1292041).

The fix is to install Unity source release 7.2.1, .  The file to be downloaded [Unity 7.2.1 "14.04 SRU 1"](https://launchpad.net/unity/+milestone/7.2.1) is also listed on the same Launchpad page.